# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^ba^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to prove the convergence of

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^ba^n$$
*when $0<a<1$

Im thinking in using the geometric series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b^na^n$$
to compare with the original series, and then prove its convergence. For that, I'm thinking of using the fact (at least I think thats a fact) that:

$$n^b<b^n$$

then

$$n^ba^n<b^na^n$$

then since the rigth part converges, the left converges too. Am I rigth? Is there na wasy way to prove it?

Comment: this is a rather nice idea, but it hits a problem if $ba \gt 1$

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you may observe that, by the ratio test, you have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{(n+1)^b\:a^{n+1}}{n^b\:a^n}\right|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\left(1+\frac1n\right)^b\right|\times |a|=1\times |a|=|a|$$ giving the convergence of the series for all complex numbers $a$ such that $|a|<1$.

Comment: but does my assumption work?